# Regex for a few words

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have few words:

```
put
returns 
between 
4paragraphs
```

How can i do regex for this? I use function preg_match in PHP. I can use only one word for this four words.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use a list of words:

```
\^[put|returns|between|4paragraphs]\$
```

Comment: Should not the `$` and `^` be swapped?

Comment: This is more correct: `^put|returns|between|4paragraphs$`, skip the `[]` brackets.

Comment: You shouldn't escape the `^` and `$` in order to keep their special meaning.